# The picture in OrderRecipeDetails does not viewing

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-mvc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tULa2.png)

When you are cliking Order you should have seen a picture of the dish
but the page is blank

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzGbz.png)

```
site.js
function showOrderRecipeDetails(orderRecipeDetails, showId) { 
    $.ajax({
        //ContentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: '/Recipe/ShowOrder',
        Data: orderRecipeDetails,
        dataType: 'html',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (htmlResult) {
            $('#' + showId).html(htmlResult);
        }
    });
}
RecipeControlers.cs
public IActionResult ShowOrder(OrderRecipeDetails orderRecipeDetails)
    {
        return PartialView("_ShowOrder", orderRecipeDetails);
    }

ShowOrder.cshtml
    @model FoodApplication.Models.OrderRecipeDetails

    <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-12">
                <img src="@Model.Image_url" class="w-100" id="order-img" />
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Typo?  The property in the jQuery AJAX options is called `data`, not `Data`.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Try checking if the `orderRecipeDetails` object contains the correct data before it is sent in the AJAX request

Comment: Uppercase "Data" won't work.